# How to get current process's UID and EUID in Linux Kernel 4.2?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

As LDD3 chapter 6 p175 show, we can get current process UID and EUID by `current->uid` and `current->euid`.
But the definition of `struct task_struct` of Linux Kernel 4.2 don't contain fields named by `uid` or `euid` any more.
So, I wonder if there are any other methods to get UID and EUID ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.uid` and `.euid` fields were moved to `struct cred`, which is now exposed as `.cred` field in `struct task_struct`. It was done in this commit: [CRED: Separate task security context from task_struct](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b6dff3ec5e116e3af6f537d4caedcad6b9e5082a). If you look at diff for `include/linux/sched.h` file, you can notice this change:

```c
-   uid_t uid,euid,suid,fsuid;
-   gid_t gid,egid,sgid,fsgid;
+   struct cred *cred;  /* actual/objective task credentials */
```

So now instead of:

```c
current->uid;
current->euid;
```

you should use:

```c
const struct cred *cred = current_cred();

cred->uid;
cred->euid;
```

Notice that `current_cred()` function should be used to access `.cred` field, as it's [RCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update) pointer.

Check out also [check_same_owner()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L3959) implementation for example.

Comment: Thanks! Following your advice, I also have found some useful MACRO in <linux/cred.h>., e.g. `current_uid()`, `current_euid()` etc, to get these current process ownership information.